# What is the closest equivalent to Qt's form layout in .NET WinForms?

Tags: .net, winforms, qt, layout

What is the closest equivalent to Qt's `QFormLayout` in .NET WinForms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TableLayoutPanel would be my call.