# Expandable column using TableLayoutPanel (from code)

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I'm trying to make the middle column of a 3-column TableLayoutPanel expandable. I'm doing it everything from code, not the designer, as a learning exercise.

The middle column has a text box and the left and right columns have a button each:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the 2nd column is not expandable yet.

I'm following the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22283690/492336 - I set the TextBox control's Dock to Fill, and also the panel's Dock to Fill as well:

```
var panel = new TableLayoutPanel();
panel.RowCount = 1;
panel.ColumnCount = 3;
panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
panel.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
panel.Controls[0].Text = "Button1";
panel.Controls[2].Text = "Button2";
panel.Controls[1].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

I also tried the suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7279996/492336 by setting the columns to `AutoSize`:

```
panel.ColumnStyles.Clear();
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
```

But that had no effect as well.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Look at your code and wonder a bit at *exactly* how those controls end up in the correct column.  You never specify the column number.  Best way to see how to program TLP correctly is use it in the designer and look at the InitializeComponent() method that the designer generated.  You'll discover the [Add() method overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he3sxc2a(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! I had checked that in another experimental code - they go from left to right and then top to bottom, sort of how you write, and if there are not enough items, the last row remains partly filled. Anyway, I changed my code to use the other overload but it had no effect. Btw I came from your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3601011/492336 - I'm trying to use TableLayoutPanel as a replacement for the Qt layouts which automatically make widgets expandable when it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to the middle column expand and occupy all remaining space in `TableLayoutPanel`, perform this settings on your controls:

- Set the first and the last column style to be `AutoSize`.
- Set the middle column style to be `Percent` with value `100`.
- Set the `Dock` property of `TextBox` to be `Fill`.

This way the middle column will expand to fill remaining space of `TableLayoutPanel`. Now if you want to `TableLayoutPanel` occupy all width of `Form`, you can set it's `Dock` property to `Fill` or `Top`. Also you can make it larger and set suitable `Anchor` for it to change it's size based in `Form` size.

```
var panel = new TableLayoutPanel();
panel.RowCount = 1;
panel.ColumnCount = 3;
panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
panel.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
panel.Controls.Add(new Button());
panel.Controls[0].Text = "Button1";
panel.Controls[2].Text = "Button2";
panel.Controls[1].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

panel.ColumnStyles.Clear();
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100)); // This is the changed part
panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
```